# No eth* interface

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I have no eth0 interface (or eth1).

```
ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tunl0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-31-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Wireless interfaces
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless_mode managed
    wireless_essid any
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface atml0 inet dhcp

# Wired or wireless interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
#... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1

Bluetooth networking
iface bnep0 inet dhcp
```

And when I try `ifup eth0` (idem for eth1) :

```
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: no shuch device
```

The only udev rule I have is in `/etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules`, and I have nothing about eth*. As I don't know the MAC adress, I can't add it.

Comment: are you running a virtual or a physical machine? do you happen to have a /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules config ? if no, is your udev-daemon running? please post the output of ps -ef | grep udev sorry i know this should be a comment, just not enough reputation yet

Comment: I've had to manually install a device myself - more information on your hardware - specifically whether this was an addon card, might be useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that (in the case of a virtual machine) you do not have a network interface specified, or (more likely - in the case of a physical machine) Linux is unaware of your network card, ie it does not have, or the drivers are not loaded.

The appropriate information to debug the problem is an output of "dmesg" and "lspci -v" which will tell what the machine is seeing - but the bottom line is you need to ensure your card has a linux driver and this is being loaded - this would (depending on your distro) result in an "eth0" interface being visible in dmesg and ifconfig etc.

As you do not appear to have a relevant device lspci -v may help track down what the device actually is.

Comment: `dmesg` doesn't have any line concerning `eth`, and `lspci` isn't installed (it's an embedded linux generated with Yocto).

Comment: Then you should speak to people specialising in your hardware and/or Yocto project (first i've heard of it) and find out what chipset your device uses for networking and compile a kernel with support for that device.